# Correct fields of MT103 to fill information to ensure the Beneficiary would receive the payment in full without any deduction?

Tags: international-transfer, transfer, swift

We once got a situation that: even though the "OUR" option was used for Field 71A (Details of Charges), the Seller didn't receive the full original amount. Hence, the Seller's bank has advised that following information would be filled in the MT103/payment order to ensure that the full original amount would be credited successfully to the Seller's account:

Original quote:

> Please take note the below information in your payment order:
>
> - Detail of charges: OUR, FULL AMOUNT to BENEFICIARY. (meaning to be borne by the Buyer)
> - Send information to Correspondent bank (e.g. Well Fargo): charges borne  by the Sender (Buyer)

1. From what I read in the MT103 format specifications, they only specify OUR/BEN/SHA as available option, so is a phrase like "OUR, FULL AMOUNT to BENEFICIARY" accepted?
2. What is the correct field for the "Send information to Correspondent bank" as noted above?

Thanks.

Comment: It's a total pain.  There's just nothing you can do about this.  If one of the banks along the way decides to take a fee - they take it  :/  Could you possibly use a different bank or service to send ?

Comment: My company is an Agent trying to help with the situation. The Buyer and the Seller are actually in a controversy at the moment, as the Buyer doesn't want to reimburse the shortage amount. Seller's bank advised that the intermediary bank was JPMorgan Chase, don't know if Citibank or Wells Fargo would be better.